# Find the radius of convergence, R, of the series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Find the interval $I$ of convergence of the series
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 9 (-1)^n n x^n.$$
>
> (Enter your answer using interval notation.)

I'm stuck with this problem and could use a ton of help.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I've formatted your equation for legibility, please take a look at the source code and then consult one of the above links for more info.

Comment: Ratio Test or Root Test will do it.  If I am reading the question right (hard) there will be obvious divergence at the boundaries $\pm 1$ of the interval of convergence.

Comment: thanks for the format links, i'll be sure to use them in the future!

Answer (score 1):

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{n+1}n|x|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|x|$$

So it has to be...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how much this could help; so forgive me if I am off-topic.

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 9 (-1)^n n x^n=9x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^n n x^{n-1}=9x\frac{d}{dx}\Big(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^n  x^{n}\Big)$$ $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  (-1)^n  x^{n}=-1+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  (-1)^n  x^{n}=-1+\frac{1}{x+1}=-\frac{x}{x+1}$$ Derive and get $$S=-\frac{9 x}{(x+1)^2}$$ from which the problem becomes quite clear.